# Delphi & Absolute database : Delete Query

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

Why is it that my query does not work ?

```
Form1.ABSQuery1.Close;
Form1.ABSQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.ABSQuery1.SQL.Text:='DELETE FROM LOG WHERE status = ''YES'' and DATE BETWEEN :d1 and :d2';
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d1').Value :=cxDateEdit1.Date;
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d2').Value :=cxDateEdit2.Date;
Form1.ABSQuery1.ExecSQL;
Form1.ABSTable1.Refresh;
```

I get this error :

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does it not delete the record(s) you expect? Do you get an SQL Error?  Can you provide more info on what the actual issue is

Comment: What happens if you parenthesize: `(DATE BETWEEN :d1 and :d2)`?

Comment: It could be DATE is being interpreted as a function maybe? Is DATE really the name of one of your columns?  If so, rename your DATE field to something else and try again.

Comment: 'delete from LOG where status = ''YES'' and (DATE BETWEEN :d1 and :d2)'; -  nothing gets deleted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `AsDateTime` in your `Params` setting code.

```
Form1.ABSQuery1.SQL.Text:='DELETE FROM LOG WHERE status = ''YES'' and DATE BETWEEN :d1 and :d2';
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d1').AsDateTime :=cxDateEdit1.Date;
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d2').AsDateTime :=cxDateEdit2.Date;
Form1.ABSQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Using `Value` converts the `cxDateEdit1.Date` to a generic string format for assignment, and that doesn't properly convert it to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format that most databases (including ABS) expect. Properly using `AsDateTime` allows the database driver/component to convert to the specific date format the DBMS uses.

Also, is your database field really named `DATE`? Date is usually a reserved word or function name in most DBMS, and if it is it usually needs to be quoted.

Comment: It had me baffled for a while as I, at first, used .asDate. Adding time, it seems , does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d1').DataType := ftDateTime;
Form1.ABSQuery1.Params.ParamByName('d1').Value :=cxDateEdit1.Date;
```

You must explicitly specify the data type of the parameter to it had no such problem, and then convert to a string does not need to